# Strange mobile nav issue on iOS

Tags: ios, css, mobile, nav

I'm trying to create a simple mobile nav menu. It looks fine on desktop Chrome, but I have noticed a couple of issues on my iPhone 6 Plus:

Safari: When tapping the hamburger to open the menu, the cross is moving when it should be in the same place as the hamburger.

Chrome: Above issue isn't present, however I have noticed an intermittent issue where the hamburger/cross get mixed up and show at the wrong time (eg: cross showing when menu closed).

I presume I've done something fundamentally wrong here - can anyone please help? :)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sad_muso/pen/pbkLNW

I presume it may be related to this CSS that is applied when menu is open:

```
ul.topnav.responsive li a {
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px 5px;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: this effect is caused because you use 2 different typos for the close-open hamburger. that's why you habe to give your "x" (or .open class) a fon-size of 2em. I'll remove the 'li class="icon"' from the ul and add it as a span before the ul. then I'll use icon-fonts for the hamburger (or better svgs).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice Marouen Mhiri. I have found icomoon icons to use and am currently trying those out to see if they resolve my issue :)

Comment: yepp! I hope this will fix your issue